# How to create an async function that never resolves?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

It's easy to create a Promise that never resolves, by passing a function that does not call the `resolve` callback:

```js
const p = new Promise(() => {})
```

How can I create an `async` function that does the same?

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  // ???
}
```

Comment: Why would this be useful?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have certain functions that expect a promise, but times out after a while. Passing a "never resolve" promise can be used to force the timeout behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either explicitly return such a Promise from it

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  return new Promise(() => {});
}

neverResolve()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```

Or `await` one.

```js
async function neverResolve() {
  await new Promise(() => {});
}

neverResolve()
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log)
```